# increment a number in text file, language c

Tags: c, printf, scanf, fopen

My function below have to increment a number in a file, which doesn't exists at the begining. The first "if" is when the file is empty, and the second one is to make "id++" in my file and return it, but this increment doesn't work, if I call 4 times the function, it return "0101". Thanks for the help.

```
int genererId(){
int id=0;
FILE * fichier = fopen("id.txt","w");
fclose(fichier);
fichier = fopen("id.txt","r");
if (fichier != NULL){

    if(fscanf(fichier,"%d",&id)!=EOF){
        fclose(fichier);
        FILE * fichier = fopen("id.txt","w");
        fprintf(fichier, "%d", 1);
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("%d",id);
        fclose(fichier);
        FILE * fichier = fopen("id.txt","w");
        id++;
        fprintf(fichier, "%d",id);
        fclose(fichier);
        return id;
    }
}

return -1;
}


int main(){
    printf("%d",genererId());
    printf("%d",genererId());
    printf("%d",genererId());
    printf("%d",genererId());
    printf("%d",genererId());
    printf("%d",genererId());
    printf("%d",genererId());
}
```

Current output : `01010101010101`
Expected output : `1234567`

Comment: Ideally, you should test `if (fichier != NULL)` *before* you read from that file. *Undefined behaviour* beckons. You should also test the return value from `fscanf` which is provided for your benefit. `if (fscanf(...) != ...) { /* evasive action */ }`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "increment file"? Show example pairs of input and desired output.

Comment: Please don't correct errors in the code posted unless it was not your actual code. Rolled back.

Comment: i'm expected just an output, in my file there're number like 1, and after call, return 2 and replace 1 by 2 in my file @Yunnosch

Comment: It would help if you show **in the question** the input, the expected output, and the actual output. By formal example, not by narrative.

Comment: I expected 1234567

Comment: What was difficult about **in the question**? I see you corrected the code on the question yet again. Please don't do that, in response to suggestions. The end point could be perfect code posted, and useless comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int genID()
{
    int val ;
    FILE * fp = fopen("file.txt", "r") ;
    if (!fp) {
        fp = fopen("file.txt", "w") ;
        if (!fp) return -1 ; // fail
        fprintf(fp, "%d", 1) ;
        fclose(fp) ;
        return 1;
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &val) ;
    val++;

    fclose(fp); // close file for read
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "w") ; // reopen for write
    fprintf(fp, "%d", val) ;
    fclose(fp) ;
    return val ;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", genID()); // 1
    printf("%d", genID()); // 2
    printf("%d", genID()); // 3
    return 0 ;
}
```

and next run will get 4, 5, 6, ...etc.

Comment: Thank's ! i think i've an issue in my computer because your function return me `11111111111`and 1 more when i call it one more time, i will try on an other computer maybe

Comment: What is your compiler ? I compile this program with `gcc incfile.c`.

Comment: Delete your file "id.txt", before. Maybe change `fopen("file.txt", "w")` to `fopen("file.txt", "w+")`. Then compile and run your program again.

Comment: i'm using codeblocks, it use classis GNU GCC compiler

Comment: With an other compiler it works ! thank's again for help !